# "Element must be user-editable in order to clear it" error

Tags: selenium, cucumber, webdriver, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

> Element must be user-editable in order to clear it
>   (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidElementStateError) (eval):2:in
>   `attach_file'

When I run my feature that has `attach_file` step in it, it gives me this error.

Here is the line of my feature that fails:

```
And I attach the file "images/cakes/1.jpeg" to "file_field"
```

and here is my step definition:

```
When /^(?:|I )attach the file "([^"]*)" to "([^"]*)"(?: 
within "([^"]*)")?$/ do |path, field, selector|
  with_scope(selector) do
    attach_file(field, path)
  end
end
```

Does any body know what the problem is?

Comment: Didn't the tested page change, too? The `file_field` is a `<input type="file" />` element, right?

Comment: The page has not changed.                                       <input id="file_field" name="file_field" size="30" type="file">

Answer (score 2):

There is issue in capybara. You need to update to 1.1.2. See [github](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/541).